# UIAlertView + UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, uialertview

I'm looking for some help. I need to know how to achieve multiline text input on a UIAlertView. I'm not looking to use a UITextField, that has single line input.

Before UIAlertViews were deprecated I use to do it with something like this:

```
    -(IBAction)addComment:(id)sender
{
    //multiline comments
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Export"
                                                        message:@"Save this report to the feed with a comment?"
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];

    alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    UITextView *textView = [UITextView new];
    [alertView setValue: textView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
    alertView.tag = 3;
    [alertView show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //Check for confirmation on exporting.
    if (alertView.tag == 3) {
        UITextView *textView = [UITextView new];
        [alertView setValue: textView forKey:@"accessoryView"];
        if (buttonIndex == 1)[self writeData:textView.text];
    }
}
```

iOS8+ this doesn't seem to work for me, the data coming from the textView is always empty.

Comment: I'm not sure about adding a subview to `UIAlertViewController` although it is a subclass of `UIViewController` so you may be able to add a `UITextView` to the view property (I haven't tried this). Otherwise have you thought about creating your own UIAlertController style class?

Comment: `UIAlertView` is meant to be used as-is. You are not supposed to add subviews or make modifications. The docs state: *"The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."*.

Comment: @RASS The question is about `UIAlertView`, not `UIAlertController`. There is no such thing as `UIAlertViewController`.

Comment: My Apologies typo on the name.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html

Comment: Sorry, typo. I do hope you'll forgive me. My comment was a suggestion on how you might be able to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to know how to achieve multiline text input on a UIAlertView

You don't. If you need more than what a built-in UIAlertView gives you, make your own presented view controller that *looks* and *acts* like a UIAlertView, except that the view is your view and you can customize it however you like.

Comment: See my article on this topic: http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/01/transcending-uialertview-on-ios-7.html

Comment: And sample code: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7

Comment: Thanks Matt, this will work great.

Comment: Feel free to steal my code! That's what it's for.